# discord.js "TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined" with async function in command file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to add a command code under the command file, but i'm unable to get it to work. The problem arises at this line => **if (command == 'checkin' || command == 'ch') {
client.commands.get('chk').execute(message)**.

Without that line, the code works fine with the other 2 commands. I think it has to do with the async function but I'm not sure how to solve this problem. I don't want to include the whole chunk of code in the main file either, as it gets very long and cluttered. I'm new to coding, so it might be something I can't understand yet - please help me!

bot.js (the main .js file)

```
const { token, prefix } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const db = require('quick.db');
const ms = require('parse-ms-2')
const { Client, Intents, Message, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
});

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

// filter commands 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// fetch commands
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("online.");
    client.user.setPresence({ activties: [{ name: 'with commands' }] });
})



client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    // definite command components
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    if (command == 'help' || command == 'h') {
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message)
    }

    if (command == 'bal') {
        client.commands.get('bal').execute(message)
    }

    if (command == 'checkin' || command == 'ch') {
        client.commands.get('chk').execute(message)
    }
})

client.login(token)
```

chk.js (where the command is)

```
const db = require('quick.db')
const nm = require('parse-ms-2')

module.exports = {
    name: "check in",
    descrption: "daily check in rewards.",
    async execute(message) {
    let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    let daily = await db.fetch(`daily_${message.author.id}`);
    let money = db.fetch(`money_${user.id}`);
    let cooldown = 1000*60*60*20
    let amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 250

        if (daily != null && cooldown - (Date.now() - daily) > 0) {
            let time = ms(cooldown - (Date.now() - daily));
            message.channel.send(`You have already collected the daily check in reward, please check in again in **${time.hours}h ${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s**`)
        } else {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Daily Check In')
            .setDescription(`Here is the amount collected today: ${amount}`)
            .setColor('#ffc300')
            message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})

            db.add(`money_${message.author.id}`, amount)
            db.add(`daily_${message.author.id}`, Date.now())
        }
}}
```

Comment: _"I think it has to do with the async function"_ - That's not what the error tells you. `client.commands.get('chk')` returns `undefined`

Comment: `"chk" !== "check in"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"`

Means `client.commands.get('chk')` is returning `undefined`.
Presumably, this means the `chk` command can't be found.

So, let's look at where you're setting the commands:

```js
// fetch commands
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

And let's check your `chk.js` file which is being imported.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "check in",
    // ...
```

What I can see is, you're exporting the module and setting the command with the name `"check in"` but later in the script, you're asking for a command called `"chk"`. The command can't be found, returns `undefined`, and kills your code as it isn't handled.

The solution in this case is to just change your `name` property to `"chk"`, or request `client.commands.get("check in")` instead.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked!! I genuinely thought the name was just a tag for myself to see, which explains why I never made the correlation. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Feel free to mark this answer as correct, and I hope your bot does well! 